# Django can't find model property

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, I have a models.py that looks like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class Battle(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.battle_name

    battle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When I drop to the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`), I can't interact either of the DateTimeField properties.

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from battles.models import Battle
>>> Battle.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Battle: my first battle>, <Battle: Take back the motherland>, <Battle: this is the big one>]>
>>> Battle.objects.filter(battle_name='my first battle')
<QuerySet [<Battle: my first battle>]>
>>> import datetime
>>> Battle.objects.filter(end_time<datetime.datetime.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'end_time' is not defined
>>> Battle.objects.filter(end_time < datetime.datetime.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'end_time' is not defined
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let me add a bit of explanation..**

```
Battle.objects.filter(end_time < datetime.datetime.now())
```

here `filter()` is a callable that accepts arguments (args or kwargs). With the above code you are trying to pass a boolean value (`object < object`) to the filter callable as argument. Now, does a boolean value `True` or `False` specify anything about a model field?

What you should be doing is pass a keyword argument, namely

```
Battle.objects.filter(end_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Now the `filter()` gets the info it needs, the kwarg parameter `end_time__lt` (which specifies the model field along with the compare method) and the value that needs to be compared with `datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 3):

You make syntax error

**Try this**

```
Battle.objects.filter(end_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now())
```